# How can I execute a JavaScript file easily?

Tags: javascript, development-environment

When I learned Perl and Python, my "development environment" consisted of vim and a shell. I would simply write the program in vim, then execute it from the command line. I am aware that the spidermonkey engine is available as a standalone interpreter, but I'm not sure how practical it is.

The "intuitive" way with JS would be to incorporate the script into a web page and view it in different browsers, but that seems cumbersome. I have seen some recommendations for Firebug, but I couldn't quite get the hang of it.

I know there are several JS-oriented plugins for vim, but again I don't know how practical any are.

I basically want to write a script, and check it for syntax and output, quickly. I am also interested to know how actual JS developers go about testing their code.

Comment: Yes, such CLI engines exist. Which have you tried? Also, what DOM support, if any, is needed? If the DOM is needed from the CLI, look up "headless javascript". For *just* syntax checking, jslint or similar might be sufficient.

Comment: I test in a browser, always :) Well, Node.js is what I use for really quick stuff. (I also use it as a calculator.)

Answer (score 1):

I use [Node.js](http://nodejs.com) a lot, so my answer will be biased by that, but...

1. For learning the language, Node.js gives you an easy-to-use (like Python, Ruby, et al) REPL by just typing `node` at the command line.
2. Validation of your website is nicely done with [Zombie](http://zombie.labnotes.org), a headless browser implemented in Node.js. If your Javascript is syntactically wrong, as soon as you try to load the page you'll get an error. If your Javascript is semantically wrong (bad logic), then the tests you write to verify proper behavior of the code will fail.
3. You'll eventually *have* to test in Firefox, IE, etc, but not really in Chrome because they both use the same V8 engine (you might want to do a cursory glance, of course). IE, as you probably know, has the greatest number of deviations from the other browsers by not implementing features or giving them a different name. Firefox, surprisingly, is also quite deviant, but not in missing features but in having many extra features in the Javascript language that no other browser has (they proposed as part of the ECMAScript standard but were rejected) so it's actually a *good* idea not to start from there if you want your code to run on every interpreter.

With Node.js you'll also have one of the faster server-side interpreters at your command (faster than Python and Ruby, roughly equal to Lua, and sometimes up to Java's level, and somehow V8 has the fastest RegEx engine in the world), and then server-side code matches client-side code, which makes things like RPC layers much nicer to work with.